# How to find entries that are within a given timespan in sql?

Tags: sql, date

I have a table with some entries, and columns such as itemsbought and starttime and endtime. The start and end time are like dd/yy hh:mm:ss format. But given a time span of say from Jan 1 to Jan 20, how do I find the sum of itemsbought ?

I am not sure its straightforward because what if there are entries that start on Jan15 and end on Feb20. There is no way to tell how many of those items were bought withing Jan15 to 20, because only those entries need to be included in my count...

How would you approach this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `starttime` and `endtime` are actually `datetime` types and not text, try this:

```
SELECT SUM(itemsbought)
FROM items
WHERE starttime BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-20'
  AND endtime BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-20'
```

This way, if either the `starttime` or `endtime` fall outside the range you want, they will not be included.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to ask whoever will be using the output from the query, how they would want it to be handled.

The options that seem most appropriate to me would be:

1. Only include entries where starttime is within the specified date range (ie. ignore endtime).
2. Only include entries where endtime is within the specified date range (ie. ignore starttime).
3. Pro-rata the itemsbought (and any other appropriate quantities) by the proportion of the record date range that is within the specified date range.

There are probably already business rules defined for this scenario - I suspect that option 2. is the most likely.